# GET not supported although I am using PUT in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, crud

I am using Laravel 7 and I can add entries and view them from the database. When I try to edit or update edited changes, I either get a warning from Laravel saying that the The `GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: PUT`. However, I am using PUT in both the web.php route as well as in my method calls. Surely I am doing something wrong.
Here is a view of my Routes calling artisan route:list
[image: Route:list]

in my Route Group in web.php Here are the controllers I am calling:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'isAdmin']], function () {
    Route::get('/dashboard', function () {
        return view('admin.dashboard');
    });

    Route::get('registered-user', 'Admin\RegisteredController@index');
    Route::get('registered-empresa', 'Admin\EmpresaController@index');
    Route::get('role-edit/{id}', 'Admin\RegisteredController@edit');
    Route::put('role-update/{id}', 'Admin\RegisteredController@updaterole');
    Route::post('save-empresa', 'Admin\EmpresaController@store');
    Route::put('edit-empresa/{id}', 'Admin\EmpresaController@update');
});
```

Here is the update function I created in EmpresaController.php:

```
 public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'erfc' => 'required',
            'enombre' => 'required',
            'ecalle' => 'required',
            'ecolonia' => 'required',
            'eciudad' => 'required',
            'eestado' => 'required',
            'ecpostal' => 'required',
            'epais' => 'required',
        ]);

        $empr = Empresa::find($id);

        $empr->erfc = $request->input('erfc');
        $empr->enombre = $request->input('enombre');
        $empr->ecalle = $request->input('ecalle');
        $empr->ecolonia = $request->input('ecolonia');
        $empr->eciudad = $request->input('eciudad');
        $empr->eestado = $request->input('eestado');
        $empr->ecpostal = $request->input('ecpostal');
        $empr->epais = $request->input('epais');

        $empr->update();

        return redirect('/registered-empresa')->with('status', 'Empresa se actualizó correctamente.');
    }
```

And finally, here is the location of my empresas table where I both add, view and update my table in my index.blade.php file:

```
@extends('layouts.admin')


@section('content')
<div class="container-fluid mt-5">

    <!-- Heading -->
    <div class="card mb-4 wow fadeIn">

      <!--Card content-->
      <div class="card-body d-sm-flex justify-content-between">

        <h4 class="mb-2 mb-sm-0 pt-1">
          <a href="/">Home Page</a>
          <span>/</span>
          <span>Empresas Registradas</span>
        </h4>
        @if (session('status'))
            <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                {{ session('status') }}
            </div>
        @endif
        <div class="modal fade" id="modalRegisterForm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header text-center">
                    <h4 class="modal-title w-100 font-weight-bold">Añadir Empresa</h4>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <form action="/save-empresa" method="POST">
                    {{ csrf_field() }}
                <div class="modal-body mx-3">
                    <div class="md-form mb-1">
                        <input type="text" name="erfc" id="orangeForm-erfc" class="form-control validate">
                        <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="orangeForm-erfc">RFC</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="md-form mb-1">
                        <input type="text" name="enombre" id="orangeForm-enombre" class="form-control validate">
                        <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="orangeForm-enombre">Nombre</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="md-form mb-1">
                        <input type="text" name="ecalle" id="orangeForm-ecalle" class="form-control validate">
                        <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="orangeForm-ecalle">Calle</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="md-form mb-1">
                        <input type="text" name="ecolonia" id="orangeForm-ecolonia" class="form-control validate">
                        <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="orangeForm-ecolonia">Colonia</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="md-form mb-1">
                        <input type="text" name="eciudad" id="orangeForm-eciudad" class="form-control validate">
                        <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="orangeForm-eciudad">Ciudad</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="md-form mb-1">
                        <input type="text" name="eestado" id="orangeForm-eestado" class="form-control validate">
                        <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="orangeForm-eestado">Estado</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="md-form mb-1">
                        <input type="text" name="ecpostal" id="orangeForm-ecpostal" class="form-control validate">
                        <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="orangeForm-ecpostal">Codigo Postal</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="md-form mb-1">
                        <input type="text" name="epais" id="orangeForm-epais" class="form-control validate">
                        <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="orangeForm-epais">País</label>
                    </div>
                    <div style="display: none;" class="md-form mb-1">
                    <input type="text" name="euser" readonly id="orangeForm-euser" class="form-control validate" value="{{ Auth::user()->id }}">

                    </div>
                    <div style="display: none;" class="md-form mb-1">
                        <input type="text" name="eregby" readonly id="orangeForm-eregby" class="form-control validate" value="{{ Auth::user()->id }}">

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer d-flex justify-content-center">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-deep-orange">Añadir</button>
                </div>
            </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
<div class="text-center">
  <a href="" class="btn btn-default btn-rounded mb-4" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalRegisterForm"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp; Add</a>
</div>


<!--edit modal start-->

<div class="modal fade" id="editModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header text-center">
            <h4 class="modal-title w-100 font-weight-bold">Editar Empresa</h4>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <form action="edit-empresa/" id="editForm">
            {{ csrf_field() }}
            @method('PUT')
                <div class="modal-body mx-3">
                    <div class="md-form mb-1">
                        <input placeholder="RFC" type="text" name="erfc" id="erfc" class="form-control validate">
                    </div>
                    <div class="md-form mb-1">
                        <input placeholder="Nombre" type="text" name="enombre" id="enombre" class="form-control validate">

                    </div>
                    <div class="md-form mb-1">
                        <input placeholder="Calle" type="text" name="ecalle" id="ecalle" class="form-control validate">

                    </div>
                    <div class="md-form mb-1">
                        <input placeholder="Colonia" type="text" name="ecolonia" id="ecolonia" class="form-control validate">

                    </div>
                    <div class="md-form mb-1">
                        <input placeholder="Ciudad" type="text" name="eciudad" id="eciudad" class="form-control validate">

                    </div>
                    <div class="md-form mb-1">
                        <input placeholder="Estado" type="text" name="eestado" id="eestado" class="form-control validate">

                    </div>
                    <div class="md-form mb-1">
                        <input placeholder="Codigo Postal" type="text" name="ecpostal" id="ecpostal" class="form-control validate">

                    </div>
                    <div class="md-form mb-1">
                        <input placeholder="País" type="text" name="epais" id="epais" class="form-control validate">
                    </div>
                    <div style="display: none;" class="md-form mb-1">
                        <input type="text" name="euser" readonly id="euser" class="form-control validate" value="{{ Auth::user()->id }}">
                    </div>
                    <div style="display: none;" class="md-form mb-1">
                        <input type="text" name="eregby" readonly id="eregby" class="form-control validate" value="{{ Auth::user()->id }}">
                    </div>
                </div>
                {{-- <div class="modal-footer d-flex justify-content-center">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-deep-orange">Editar</button>
                </div> --}}
                <div class="modal-footer d-flex justify-content-center">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-deep-orange">Editar</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!--end edit modal-->

      </div>

    </div>
    <!-- Heading -->

    <!--Grid row-->
      <!--Grid column-->
      <div class="row">
        <!--Card-->
        <div class="col-md-12 mb-4">
          <!--Card content-->
          <div class="card">
            <!-- List group links -->
             <div class="card-body">

                <table id="datatable2" class="table table-bordered">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                           <th>RFC</th>
                           <th>Nombre</th>
                           <th>Calle</th>
                           <th>Colonia</th>
                           <th>Ciudad</th>
                           <th>Estado</th>
                           <th>Codigo Postal</th>
                           <th>País</th>
                           <th>Acción</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        @foreach ($empresas as $empresa)
                         <tr>
                         <td>{{ $empresa->erfc }}</td>
                         <td>{{ $empresa->enombre }}</td>
                         <td>{{ $empresa->ecalle }}</td>
                         <td>{{ $empresa->ecolonia }}</td>
                         <td>{{ $empresa->eciudad }}</td>
                         <td>{{ $empresa->eestado }}</td>
                         <td>{{ $empresa->ecpostal }}</td>
                         <td>{{ $empresa->epais }}</td>

                         <td>
                            <div class="text-center">
                                <a href="" class="badge badge-pill btn-primary px-3 py-2 edit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editModal">Editar</a>

                            <a class="badge badge-pill btn-danger px-3 py-2" href="">Borrar</a>
                        </div>
                         </td>
                         </tr>
                        @endforeach
                    </tbody>
                </table>

            </div>
            <!-- List group links -->
          </div>
        </div>
        <!--/.Card-->
      </div>
      <!--Grid row-->
  </div>
@endsection

@section('scripts')
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    let table = $('#datatable2').DataTable();

    // Start edit record
        table.on('click', '.edit', function() {
            $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
            if($($tr).hasClass('child')) {
                $tr = $tr.prev('.parent');
            }

            let data = table.row($tr).data();
            console.log(data);

            $('#erfc').val(data[0]);
            $('#enombre').val(data[1]);
            $('#ecalle').val(data[2]);
            $('#ecolonia').val(data[3]);
            $('#eciudad').val(data[4]);
            $('#eestado').val(data[5]);
            $('#ecpostal').val(data[6]);
            $('#epais').val(data[7]);

            $('#editForm').attr('action', '/edit-empresa/'+data[0]);
            $('#editModal').modal('show');
        });
    // End edit record
});
</script>
@endsection
```

I am pretty sure it is in this file that I am doing something wrong. Any help on how I can do this better or if I missed something, I would surely appreciate it. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify method as `POST` when defining the form even though you are including the `@method('PUT')` inside the form. That is because HTML does not support `PUT` method directly, and by default it will be a `GET`. So to correct:

Change this:

```
<form action="edit-empresa/" id="editForm">
```

TO

```
<form action="edit-empresa/" id="editForm" method="POST">
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply user3532758. I added method="PUT" but I am still getting the: The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: PUT. message. Anything else you can think of? :) Thank you.

Comment: you need to add `method=POST` because PUT is not supported in HTML. the `@method('PUT') will only take effect once the form has been POSTed. Edited the answer for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

**in web.php**

```
Route::patch('edit-empresa/{id}', 'Admin\EmpresaController@update');
```

**index.blade.php**

```
@method('PATCH')
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason I could not get this to work using the modal and jquery method so I eliminated the datatables jquery from the bottom of the index.blade.php. My first error was to not call the data first. I created a seperate file called edit.blade.php within the view-admin-empresa folder. Here is the code:

```
@extends('layouts.admin')


@section('content')
<div class="container-fluid mt-5">

<!-- Heading -->
<div class="card mb-4 wow fadeIn">

    <!--Card content-->
    <div class="card-body d-sm-flex justify-content-between">

      <h4 class="mb-2 mb-sm-0 pt-1">
        <span>Empresa Registrada - Editar Empresa</span>
      </h4>
    </div>

  </div>
  <!-- Heading -->
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
                <h4 class="card-title">Editar Empresa</h4>
            <form action="{{ url('empresa-update/'.$empresa->id) }}" id="editForm" method="POST">
                    {{ csrf_field() }}
                    {{ method_field('PUT') }}
                        <div class="modal-body mx-3">
                            <div class="md-form mb-1">
                            <label for="erfc">RFC</label>
                            <input value="{{ $empresa->erfc }}" type="text" name="erfc" id="erfc" class="form-control validate">
                            </div>
                            <div class="md-form mb-1">
                                <label for="enombre">Nombre</label>
                                <input value="{{ $empresa->enombre }}" type="text" name="enombre" id="enombre" class="form-control validate">

                            </div>
                            <div class="md-form mb-1">
                                <label for="ecalle">Calle</label>
                                <input value="{{ $empresa->ecalle }}" type="text" name="ecalle" id="ecalle" class="form-control validate">

                            </div>
                            <div class="md-form mb-1">
                                <label for="ecolonia">Colonia</label>
                                <input value="{{ $empresa->ecolonia }}" type="text" name="ecolonia" id="ecolonia" class="form-control validate">

                            </div>
                            <div class="md-form mb-1">
                                <label for="ecuidad">Ciudad</label>
                                <input value="{{ $empresa->eciudad }}" type="text" name="eciudad" id="eciudad" class="form-control validate">

                            </div>
                            <div class="md-form mb-1">
                                <label for="eestado">Estado</label>
                                <input value="{{ $empresa->eestado }}" type="text" name="eestado" id="eestado" class="form-control validate">

                            </div>
                            <div class="md-form mb-1">
                                <label for="ecpostal">Codigo Postal</label>
                                <input value="{{ $empresa->ecpostal }}" type="text" name="ecpostal" id="ecpostal" class="form-control validate">

                            </div>
                            <div class="md-form mb-1">
                                <label for="epais">País</label>
                                <input value="{{ $empresa->epais }}" type="text" name="epais" id="epais" class="form-control validate">
                            </div>
                            <div style="display: none;" class="md-form mb-1">
                                <input type="text" name="euser" readonly id="euser" class="form-control validate" value="{{ Auth::user()->id }}">
                            </div>
                            <div style="display: none;" class="md-form mb-1">
                                <input type="text" name="eregby" readonly id="eregby" class="form-control validate" value="{{ Auth::user()->id }}">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="modal-footer d-flex justify-content-center">
                        <a href="{{ url('registered-empresa') }}" class="btn btn-secondary">Cancelar</a>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-deep-orange">Editar</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Then in the web.php, I created the following routes:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'isAdmin']], function () {
    Route::get('/dashboard', function () {
        return view('admin.dashboard');
    });

    Route::get('registered-user', 'Admin\RegisteredController@index');
    Route::get('registered-empresa', 'Admin\EmpresaController@index');
    Route::get('role-edit/{id}', 'Admin\RegisteredController@edit');
    Route::put('role-update/{id}', 'Admin\RegisteredController@updaterole');
    Route::post('save-empresa', 'Admin\EmpresaController@store');
    Route::get('/edit-empresa/{id}', 'Admin\EmpresaController@edit');
    Route::put('/empresa-update/{id}', 'Admin\EmpresaController@update');
});
```

As mentioned earlier, I eliminated the edit modal and redirected to the empresa edit.blade.php file.
Now, I am able to edit without any problems. Thank you to ***Arjun bhati*** and  ***user3532758*** for taking a stab at this issue. I really appreciate it.